# ASP.NET Core how to upload image to SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to do a simple app to register users to a database with name, surname, profile photo etc. then edit or delete them. I am planning to upload the image as `IFileForm`, then convert it to `varbinary` for SQL Server. But I am having a problem on how to implement uploading the image. The code works for other members. Any help would be appreciated.

My user model class for API

```
public partial class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; };
    public string UserName { get; set; };
    public string UserSurname { get; set; };
    public string UserBirthdate { get; set; };
    public byte[] UserPicture { get; set; };
}
```

Post method for my API

```
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user)
{
    _context.UserTable1s.Add(user);

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        if (UserExists(user.UserId))
        {
             return Conflict();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    } 

    return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.UserId }, user);
}
```

My user model for Web App

```
public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserSurname { get; set; }
    public string UserBirthdate { get; set; }
    public IFormFile UserPicture { get; set; }
}
```

Post method for Web App to consume API

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(User user)
{
    User receivedUser = new User();

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:7252/api/Users", content))
        {
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            receivedUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(apiResponse);
        }
    }

    return View(receivedUser);
}
```

And finally the view for AddUser. Removed the code for other members because too long.

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddUser" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            /*some more code here for other members*/
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserPicture" type="file"class="control-label">User Picture</label>
                <input asp-for="UserPicture" type="file" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserPicture" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

EDIT:
I managed to make it work after editing vega_gf's answer a little. I am pretty sure it is not the most optimal way but it works for now.

My AddUser method now:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(User user, [FromForm]IFormFile imgfile)
{
    User receivedUser = new User();
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
            if (imgfile != null)
            {
                using var dataStream = new MemoryStream();
                await imgfile.CopyToAsync(dataStream);
                byte[] imageBytes = dataStream.ToArray();
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                user.UserPicture = base64String;
            }
        
        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:7252/api/Users", content))
        {
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            receivedUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(apiResponse);
        }
    }
    return View(receivedUser);
}
```

Added an IFormFile imgfile property to my model and used it in view like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="imgfile" type="file"class="control-label">User Picture</label>
                <input asp-for="imgfile" type="file" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="imgfile" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the result you get from `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user)` before it gets added to the `StringContent` constructor.

Comment: is your client web app MVC or razor pages?
Can you please share the content of the class that handles the post method
and the json result that you get from the Serialization

Comment: Iti s MVC. I am trying to put a breakpoint to see the json results but then the form the add user doesn't appear at all. Sorry I am pretty new. Also what do you mean exactly by the class that handles the post method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would change image type to string(optional)

Then on your AddUser method you add this

```
[BindProperty]
public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
public string Msg { get; set; }  
public static readonly List<string> ImageExtensions = new() { ".JPG", ".BMP", ".PNG" }; //to restrict file extensions


if (HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)// check if the user uploded something
{
     ImageFile = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.GetFile("file_Main");
     if (ImageFile != null)
     {
          var extension = Path.GetExtension(ImageFile.FileName);//get file name
          if (ImageExtensions.Contains(extension.ToUpperInvariant()))
          {
              using var dataStream = new MemoryStream();
              await ImageFile.CopyToAsync(dataStream);
              byte[] imageBytes = dataStream.ToArray(); // you can save this to your byte array variable and remove the 2 lines below
              string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
              User.UserPicture = base64String; // to save the image as base64String 
              }
              else
              {
                  Msg = "image format must be in JPG, BMP or PNG"; //Custom error message
                  return Page();
              }
          }
      }
}
```

on your view just add this

```
@if (Model.User.UserPicture != null)
{
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.UserPicture)" height="40" width="40">
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Am I supposed to add this to API or Web App? Tried both but couldn't make it work. Probably doing something wrong.

Comment: You should add it on the web app, on the function that handles the form submission

When you submit do you get all user information or all is null?

Comment: on the form add "method="post""

`<form method="post" asp-action="AddUser" ....>`

Comment: I get Incorrect Content Type error on HttpContext.Request.Form.File.

Comment: Can't get to the submit page at all.

Comment: You should better same the image path `(URL path)` in the database and image should be saved into the folder. You can get [more details here in the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/682240/best-practice-for-saving-image-in-database.html)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron in this situation a database is often more convenient than physical storage options because retrieval of a database record for user data can concurrently supply the user image

Comment: @vega_gf I managed to make it work after a few edits. Thank you.